# Creating a contingency table with fixed margins

Tags: r, statistics, contingency

I am trying to create a table with random entries from a central hypergeometric distribution where the column and row totals are fixed.

However I can get the column sums to be fixed and equal but not the row sums. I have read other answers but none seem to talk specifically about how to do it, my R knowledge is pretty basic and could do with some help or a point in the right direction.

To get the values from a central hypergeometric distribution I am using the `BiasedUrn` package.

For example:

```
N <- 50
rand <- 10
n1 <- 25
odds0 <- rep(1,K)  
m0 <- rep(N/K,K)
library(BiasedUrn)
i <- as.table(rMFNCHypergeo(nran=rand, n=n1, m=m0, odds=odds0))
addmargins(i) 
             A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J Sum
       A     5   3   5   7   5   5   6   6   5   5  52    
       B     8   7   4   5   5   6   3   4   5   4  51
       C     3   6   4   4   4   5   6   8   5   4  49
       D     4   4   6   3   6   4   5   3   3   5  43
       E     5   5   6   6   5   5   5   4   7   7  55
       Sum  25  25  25  25  25  25  25  25  25  25 250
```

Where I'm looking to keep all the column sums equal to 25, and all the row sums equal to another number which I can choose such as 50.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for the `r2dtable` function from base R?

```
set.seed(101)
tt <- r2dtable(n=1,c=rep(25,6),r=rep(50,3))
addmargins(as.table(tt[[1]]))
##       A   B   C   D   E   F Sum
## A     7   9   7  11   9   7  50
## B    10   7  10   6   7  10  50
## C     8   9   8   8   9   8  50
## Sum  25  25  25  25  25  25 150
```

Comment: Thankyou, this is exactly what i need on the margins. However is there a way to have more control over the values inside the table? Such as how they are distributed?

Comment: Fixed margins are a pretty strong constraint. `r2dtable` certainly doesn't have any more flexibility, but if you can compute a likelihood for a table under the distribution you're interested in, you might be able to do rejection sampling reasonably efficiently. Can you give more context?